# how to convert asquerable and igrouping to ienumrable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

When I use this `linq` I am getting error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2[System.Char,System.Char]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[groupBylinq.Models.employee]'.

This is my action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = from n in db.employees.Where(x => x.gender=="female")
        .GroupBy(x => x.employee_sno).ToList() select n;
    return View(result);                                    
}
```

Comment: You are mixing syntaxes in a weird way. Just use `var result = db.employees.Where(x => x.gender=="female")
        .GroupBy(x => x.employee_sno).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of GroupBy method is structure like [grouping_key, array[employee]]. But your view expect an array of employees. To achieve this you can do next

```
return View(result.SelectMany(v=>v).ToList());
```

But are you sure that you need GroupBy operator?

Comment: if it works for you, can you, please, mark it as answer, for details looks here http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thank you @sergii  sir it worked for me,and am just beginner to mvc that's the reason am practising on linq.

Comment: @anitha - i am glad to hear that my answer was helpful. Can you please mark my answer as "accepted", for more details you can take a look on the aricle http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers